# Stop Alt key bringing up the menu in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, key-bindings

I'm an Emacs user looking into Sublime Text 2. I've remapped the default Emacs key bindings and have become accustomed to moving about using Alt+i, Alt+k, Alt+j, Alt+l for up, down, left and right. I haven't had any issues remapping those keys in Sublime Text.

The problem is that whenever I use these keys to navigate the menu pops up even though I've hidden it in distraction free mode. I would like to stop the menu coming up when I press the Alt key.

If possible I would like to remap the key for displaying the menu to something else (like Alt+space). Otherwise I would like to disable the menu coming up with the Alt key altogether (and use hot keys and the console for everything).

I'm running Sublime Text on Windows XP.

Comment: Did you consider using autohotkey?

Comment: I tried autohotkey with `LAlt::return`, but that disabled the Alt key altogether, which stopped all of the Alt-* keys working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem I was having was that a key I was rebinding conflicted with a mnemonic on the menu. Specifically, I had Alt+i mapped to something while it was also the mnemonic for Find.

To fix the problem I removed the mnemonics from the menu, which stopped the menu appearing. To do this go to Preferences -> Browse Packages and open the Default/Main.sublime-menu file. In there you can remove all of the "mnemonic": "*", lines to get rid of the mnemonics.

Pressing the alt key will still bring up the menu. If you want to disable this you can use the following AutoHotkey script (thanks Armin):

```
SetTitleMatchMode RegEx
#IfWinActive .*Sublime Text 2.*
    LAlt & esc::return ;This can be any key, not just escape. It's needed to get AutoHotkey to treat Alt as a prefix key.
    ~LAlt::return
#IfWinActive
```

This only stops left Alt bringing up the menu, right Alt will still work as usual.

Comment: By any chance you have any idea about how can we do this with Sublime Text 3, this bloody thing has made my life hell. Any help would be great.

Comment: The class name of Sublime Text 3’s windows are « PX_WINDOW_CLASS » but in adapting the script I can’t make it work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Autohotkey, you can try to use [#IfWinActive](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) which will only apply hotkeys if a certain windows is active.
Then your code would look something like this

```
#IfWinActive, Emacs ; the name of the window
~LAlt::return ;this enables the LAlt + hotkey action but disables LAlt
LAlt & space::tooltip,do stuff
...
#IfWinActive ;end
```