# Change or disable modifier key (alt) which activates the application menubar in Sublime Text 3 Linux

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, sublimetext3, key-bindings, menubar

I am trying to use the package "Alternate VIM Navigation" in ST3 on Linux Ubuntu, but the alt+i and alt+h keybindings bring up the find and help menus rather than their movement keybindings:

```js
{ "keys": ["alt+i"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": false}},

{ "keys": ["alt+h"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bol", "forward": true}},
```

I have been able to disable the alt key from displaying the application menubar using CompizConfig Settings Manager, but the alt+i still brings up the find menu (and likewise for alt+h).

I have looked in many places for an answer to this, but have found nothing that works for ST3 in Linux.  Here are some related answers for OSX and Windows, and an answer in Ubuntu that suggests the CompizConfig Settings Manager:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/553687/change-or-disable-modifier-key-alt-which-activates-the-application-menubar

[Change behavior of Alt key in Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904960/change-behavior-of-alt-key-in-sublime-text-2)

[Stop Alt key bringing up the menu in Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153367/stop-alt-key-bringing-up-the-menu-in-sublime-text-2)

Any solution to this in ST3 for Linux would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried putting those key combos in your user keybindings? Go to **`Preferences -> Key Bindings-User`** and put them there.

Comment: I did try that, but it didn't give them precedence like it does in Windows...

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

1. Open Sublime's packages directory by going to Preferences > Browse Packages.
2. Open the User directory and create a file called Main.sublime-menu
3. Paste the following in:

   ```
   [
       {
           "caption": "Help",
           "mnemonic": "",
           "id": "help"
       }
   ]
   ```
4. Save the file and enjoy!

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 7, and I disabled the Tools menu instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found a bit of a strange workaround...

I have a sublime text package called "SubRed" which has a file "Main.sublime-menu" (it's in .config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SubRed - I manually installed the package).

**To disable the menubar** all I have to do is:

1. ctrl+shift+p view: toggle menu (which does not disable the menu by 
     itself for some reason),
2. open the Main.sublime-menu file in sublime,
3. save it.

Then voila, the menu bar is gone and I can finally use my Alternate Vim package key bindings without conflicting with the alt+[menubar mnemonic].

**To get the menu bar back** if needed, just simply do **ctrl+shift+p view: toggle menu.**

If anyone could suggest a better solution based on this (which doesn't involve a random 3rd party package) that would be much appreciated!

The ideal solution would be to not have to disable the menubar, but get it to work like windows where user or package defined st3 keybindings take precedence over default or system bindings.  So if "alt+i" is defined by the package as "move up a line", then it no longer opens the "Find" menu, but actually (eureka!) moves up a line!  But opening the "Find" menu is still possible with "alt, i" in sequence.